# What is required to be qualified as a ORM?

Tags: django, wordpress, orm

Is it just ability to switch databases seemlessly and forming queryies independent of the database ?

or something else is also needed to be called ORM ?

I mean `django` is supplied with a ORM !

We can use multiple databases with `Wordpress` so can we say that wordpress also has a ORM ?

I think I explained myself well..

Comment: I want to understand.. this. It matters to me !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because ORM means that the language constructs (like objects and methods)  are mapped to tables and fields and procedures on the database somehow.

If you cannot use class instances (objects) directly for database interaction and still have to rely on creating your own SQL statements, you do not have a ORM.